# Cisco Не могу получить доступ к test3

Tags: cisco, cisco-packet-tracer

[image]

Надо настроить так чтобы PC1 получил доступ к test3.ru.
Но когда я прописываю route 15.0.0.0 255.0.0.0 13.0.0.3 он пишет что это тот же роутер

Comment: Проверьте ещё адрес сети 15.0.0.0, он точно неправильный.

Answer (score 0):

следующим hopo'м должен быть адрес следующего маршрутизатора, а указанный вами адрес 13.0.0.3 - адрес текущего роутера.